# ¿Cómo extraer listas cuyo valor se repite 2 veces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Tengo la siguiente lista que dentro de ella almacena varios pares de listas:

```
x = [[1, 4], [1, 10], [2, 5], [2, 11], [3, 6], [4, 7], [4, 12], [5, 8], 
         [5, 13], [6, 9], [7, 14], [8, 15], [2, 10], [3, 11], [5, 12], [6, 13], 
         [8, 14], [9, 15]]
```

Quería saber cómo podria extraer de esta lista, las listas cuyo segundo valor se repita 2 veces, la idea es poder conseguir esto:

```
[[1, 10], [2, 11], [4, 12], [5, 13], [7, 14], [8, 15], [2, 10], [3, 11], [5, 12], [6, 13], [8, 14], [9, 15]]
```

Manualmente que podido conseguir eso mediante una *comprensión de listas*

```
y = [[a,b] for a,b in x if b == 10 or b == 11 or b == 12 or b == 13 or b == 14 or b == 15]
```

Aunque en el caso de que sea una lista más extensa esto dejaría de funcionar, podría conseguirse de una forma más efectiva? Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que el segundo item de cada sublista es un entero y que los enteros son hashables, puedes valerte de `collections.Counter` para contar las repeticiones del segundo item de cada sublista y luego usar el diccionario como filtro en una lista por compresión:

```
from collections import Counter


x = [[1, 4], [1, 10], [2, 5], [2, 11], [3, 6], [4, 7], [4, 12], [5, 8], 
     [5, 13], [6, 9], [7, 14], [8, 15], [2, 10], [3, 11], [5, 12], [6, 13], 
     [8, 14], [9, 15]]

count = Counter(sublist[1] for sublist in x)
x2 = [sublist for sublist in x if count[sublist[1]] == 2]
```

> ```
> >>> x2
> [[1, 10], [2, 11], [4, 12], [5, 13], [7, 14], [8, 15],
>  [2, 10], [3, 11], [5, 12], [6, 13], [8, 14], [9, 15]]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de obtener lo que se pide es usando `pandas` ya que la estructura de la lista que se presenta tiene forma de matriz.

```
import pandas as pd

x = [[1, 4], [1, 10], [2, 5], [2, 11], [3, 6], [4, 7], [4, 12], [5, 8], 
     [5, 13], [6, 9], [7, 14], [8, 15], [2, 10], [3, 11], [5, 12], [6, 13], 
     [8, 14], [9, 15]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=x,columns=["col1","col2"])
mask=(df.groupby(['col2']).size()==2).to_frame() # se verifica quienes se repiten dos veces
df = df[df.col2.apply(lambda x: mask.loc[x,0])] # es similar a [mask.loc[x,0] for x in df.col2.tolist()]

print(df.values.tolist())
# [[1, 10], [2, 11], [4, 12], [5, 13], [7, 14], [8, 15],
# [2, 10], [3, 11], [5, 12], [6, 13], [8, 14], [9, 15]]
```

Lo anterior también permitiría verificar si se repiten otro tipo de valores como `string`

```
x = [[1, 'clave'], [1, 10], [2, 5], [2, 11], [3, 6], [4, 7], [4, 12], [5, 8], 
     [5, 13], [6, 9], [7, 14], [8, 15], [2, 'clave'], [3, 11], [5, 12], [6, 13], 
     [8, 14], [9, 15]]
```

Resultado esperado

```
# [[1, 'clave'], [2, 11], [4, 12], [5, 13], [7, 14], [8, 15],
# [2, 'clave'], [3, 11], [5, 12], [6, 13], [8, 14], [9, 15]]
```